# How to get custom taxonomy slug(s)?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I m making a WordPress portfolio theme for the WordPress theme directory.
I created a taxonomy (name: `speciality`) for my custom post type `portfolio`. I can get the list:

```
echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'speciality', 'Portfolio Specialities: ', ', ' );
```

But I need a list of slugs for this 'speciality' taxonomy. Even I want single slug-name ' speciality's' taxonomy.

How can get this custom taxonomy's slug/slug-name list?

Comment: oh my god, nobody found for this question?

Answer (score 2):

The following code should help

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'speciality' ); 

foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    echo $term->name . " : " . $term->slug; 
}
```

Check the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) for further info